# SupportMapFragmentManagers getMapAsync() does not trigger onMapReady(GoogleMap map)

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a

```
public abstract class MyMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
  //
  public GoogleMap googleMap;
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

  @IdRes
  public abstract int getSupportMapFragId();

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     // http://stackoverflow.com/a/36592000/5102206
     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        // Do something for lollipop and above versions
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(getSupportMapFragId());
    } else {
        // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(getSupportMapFragId());
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

  }

  //..

  @Override
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
     this.googleMap = map;
  }
}
```

According to my breakpoints `onViewCreated()` is called, but onMapReady() is not called (breakpoint on `this.googleMap = map` not triggered)

On Android 5, 6 and 7 it works fine so far and I can see the Map..
On Android 4.X (API 16 - API 19) devices my app starts up, but then it seem to freeze there... I see a white blank screen.

On Android 4.X OS devices:
 1. With getFragmentManager(), the mapFragment object is null after the else condition. 
 2. With getChildFragmentMenager() the mapfragment seem to be valid and non-null, but onMapReady not triggered.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why don't use extend `SupportMapFragment` or use it directly? Android Jelly (i.e. API 16) and later cover 95.2% Google Play supported devices.

Comment: @JPVentura I did that temporarily, but that changed nothing. I had the same result.

Comment: 1. Why are you nesting `SupportMapFragment` inside `MyMapFragment`?  2. Why are you explicitly checking for an API level that nobody uses?

Comment: I have the same problem, it's real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with a blocking thread from RxJava on main thread. So it was not an Google Maps issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically

If you want to inflate a map in a fragment you can either do it in xml or do it in java code like this:

```
    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("mapFragment");
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.mapFragmentContainer, mapFragment, "mapFragment");
        ft.commit();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
}
```

And also the simple container

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, you don't need to implement the onMapReadyCallback in the class definition. Instead of **callback**  you create a new OnMapReadyCallback() right there:

```
MapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
                }
            });
```

You also need these

```
MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

I hope this helps somehow !

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you are nesting fragments, specially because it can cause [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608935/best-practice-for-nested-fragments-in-android-4-0-4-1-4-2-without-using-the).

If you take a look at [Google Samples](https://github.com/googlemaps), the [Google Maps](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap) examples uses an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [`SupportMapFragment`](https://developer.android.com/index.html?q=SupportMapFragment):

```
public class MapsActivityCurrentPlace extends AppCompatActivity
            implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks,
            OnConnectionFailedListener {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
        // info window contents.
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Return null here, so that getInfoContents() is called next.
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents,
                        (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map), false);

                TextView title = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title));
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                    this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, result.getErrorMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection suspended");
    }

}
```