# GoogleMaps in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have to implement a Mapview in an existing fragment. 
I've tried a lot of tutorials and different ways but every time I open the fragment the app ist crashing / closing with a short black screen. This one for me felt like the most closest option I've tried so far. Maybe someone has an other idea or a solution for this one.

Here is what I got so far.

Fragment:

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private SlideshowViewModel slideshowViewModel;
    GoogleMap googleMap;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        slideshowViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_slideshow);
        slideshowViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }





    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {



        LatLng Maharashtra = new LatLng(19.169257, 73.836454);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Maharashtra).title("Maharshka"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Maharashtra));

    }
}
```

The map_api.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="map_key" translatable="false" >
         MAP_KEY
    </string>
</resources>
```

And the Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_key"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>


</manifest>
```

And at least the changed gradle.build dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

I'd be thankfull if someone has an idea how to solve this problem.

Edit:

thats what it shows by trying to open the fragment in the app

```
2020-01-05 15:38:54.072 25582-25582/guti1012.info3.vnow D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-05 15:38:54.078 25582-25582/guti1012.info3.vnow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: guti1012.info3.vnow, PID: 25582
    java.lang.ClassCastException: guti1012.info3.vnow.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:443)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:184)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:212)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:823)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:808)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:745)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.java:88)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI$3.onNavigationItemSelected(NavigationUI.java:424)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:170)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:352)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-01-05 15:38:54.120 25582-25582/guti1012.info3.vnow I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25582 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What do you mean by "app is collapsing"? Do mean the app is closing--crashing? Or the view is not showing the `MapView`?

Comment: its crashing / closing

Comment: Then please edit your question and provide the stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: The issue is `SlideshowFragment cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. But from the information you have provide I do not know how the `SlideshowFragment` is defined or integrated in your app or even  where and how it is being called.

Comment: @TillG The crash message let us know that `SlideshowFragment` is not `Fragment`. SlideshowFragment is extended from `FragmentActivity` so it is an activity and you can't cast to `Fragment`.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys!! 
Had a null point exception after changing the Fragment like @LiemVo told me and got the explanation for that right there: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991087/mapfragment-getmapasyncthis-nullpointerexception