# Attempt to invoke virtual method SupportMapFragment getMapAsync on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps

### mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) returns null in map

I am trying to design an app with google map and navigation drawer, I keep on getting Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallbak)' on a null object reference error, I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


        //Implementing Google Map getChildFragmentManager
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

       /* SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }*/




        //Initializing place
        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "MY_API_KEY");
        }

        googlePlaceLocation();
        googlePlaceDestination();
    }

    private void googlePlaceLocation(){
      /*//Places Api
        places = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_location);
        places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place.getLatLng()).title(place.getName().toString()));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 12.0f));


                destination = place.getAddress().toString();
                destination = destination.replace("","+");

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, ""+status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });*/
    }

    private void googlePlaceDestination() {


// Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_destination);

        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Log.i("TAG", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
                .title("San Francisco"));

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183), 15));
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

   <!-- <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Welcome" />-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nav_host_fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) - NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991087/mapfragment-getmapasyncthis-nullpointerexception) If it does not answer your question, then you need to provide full error logs.

Comment: I've removed your API key from your question. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nav_host_fragment" />
```

You have defined a FrameLayout with id map. How can this map to a fragment automatically?

Also, it is a good practice to check for nullability of your map fragment before calling `getMapAsync`:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
if (mapFragment != null) {
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried changing to fragment and I am getting this error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer/com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class fragment"

Comment: What line is line 35?

Comment: Josh, I adjusted my code and it is now on line 21 "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer/com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment".

Comment: this is on line 21 " <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />"

Comment: But if I use this <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>", the error change to "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer/com.ckhardbyte.navigationdrawer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference"

Comment: When I comment this out "mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
", the error will disappear but the map will not load

Comment: True! The first exception shows there is something wrong with your layout. I can’t put a finger without details. Can you create a sample GitHub project. Will love to check and suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by moving the code to Home fragment

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.ckhardbyte.barzokarider.R;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    //private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    //Declaring Variables
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //Play Services
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST = 7001;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;

    DatabaseReference drivers;
    GeoFire geoFire;

    Marker mCurrent;

    //MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    private GoogleApiClient GoogleApiClient;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Geo Fire
        drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
        geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
        }

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                //Getting the user's location
                setUpLocation();

            }
        });

        return root;
    }
```

and the xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_drop_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_location"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:background="@color/quantum_black_divider">
            </View>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weightSum="6"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_map_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/place_destination"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The method setUpLocation have this code in it

```
  // For showing a move to my location button
                                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                                    // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                                    LatLng mCurrentLoc = new LatLng( -33.86, 151.20);
                                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mCurrentLoc).title("YOU"));

                                    // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mCurrentLoc).zoom(15).build();
                                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```